# What is the equivalent of the kAudioFileReadPermission in Swift for AudioFileOpenURL?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, core-audio

Do you know what is the equivalent for Swift 3.1 with the following Objective-C 2.0 code:

```
theErr = AudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)audioURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &audioFile);
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

If you use autocompletion, it will hold your hand through this process.

[image]

And when you get to that field, hit enter, and then go to the end, enter a `.` (as it's clearly an enumeration), and you can see the options:

[image]

---

But it is:

```
var audioURL: URL = ...
var audioFileID: AudioFileID?
let status = AudioFileOpenURL(audioURL as CFURL, .readPermission, .allZeros, &audioFileID)
```

Answer (score 0):

`CFURLRef` has been renamed to `CFURL`. `URL` is toll-free bridged to `CFURL`, all you need to do is cast an url to `CFURL` using `as`.

Here's the updated code for Swift 4:

```
let audioURL: URL = ...
var audioFile: AudioFileID?
let status = AudioFileOpenURL(audioURL as CFURL,
                              .readPermission,
                              0,
                              &audioFile)
```